# CakePHP ignoring $paginate property

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I've just baked a simple CakePHP app, and I'm trying to customize how records are paginated. I have this action in my controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Recipe->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('recipes', $this->Recipe->paginate());
}
```

This works fine with the default pagination. I'm trying to customize the amount of rows returned and their order by using a class property called `$paginate` in the same controller:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 1,
    'order' => array(
        'Recipe.title' => 'asc'
    )
);
```

However it's taking no effect at all. The results still have the default limit and sort order. I've also tried setting up `$this->paginate` in my action, however this seems to get ignored also:

```
public function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'order' => array(
            'Recipe.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
    $this->set('recipes', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

What could be causing Cake to ignore the pagination options I'm setting? Does it perhaps do something funky when you bake the application which I'm not aware of?

Comment: What's your exact CakePHP version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public function index() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'order' => array(
            'Recipe.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
    $this->set('recipes', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Comment: This works, although I don't understand why. Is there any way I can do it the way mentioned in the CakePHP docs, and have a global pagination setting for my entire controller?

Comment: $this->Paginator->settings set your default in the beforeFilter() of your controller. $this->paginate should still work for backward compatibility reasons. Whats your exact CakePHP version? And yes, looks like the manual is no up to date.