# How do I write a better Cakephp index() controller method?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

This problem has been bugging me for months now.  I have a CakePhp Application that I Cake Baked to get the basic CRUD functions.  So the baked Index method is this....

```
public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

The problem with this is you have no way to ORDER the results.  What I want is to be able to ORDER the result so that it displays all my users names in ascending order.

I have been able to write my own QUERY like this.....

```
public function index() {
            $this->set('users',$this->User->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY  name ASC"), $this->Paginator->paginate());

}
```

And this will ORDER my results just fine.
But the problem is it will NOT paginate at all.
I get all my 58 results down one page.

Can anyone help me write this so I can ORDER and LIMIT my results and still have Paginate() work?

Comment: Note: this might be similar to this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18450549/1167750).

Comment: Seriously, do the blog tutorial and read the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html & http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Answer (score 1):

The Paginator is pretty much just a wrapper around the `find()` method. It allows you to use the same options as a find, so you can simply set a `order` key in your Paginator settings, like this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'order' => array('name' => 'asc')
);
// Now you can paginate() with order...
$this->Paginator->paginate();
```

This is all pretty extensively documented in CakePHP's [pagination documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup).

Comment: So where do I put this Paginator Setting code?  I assume at the top of my Users Controller?

Comment: Never mind....I figured it out.  Put it in the Index Method ahead of any other code in that function.  It FINALLY works!  THANKS!